# property of an object holds value but i haven't declared any

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm declaring a object which has a following property "selectorText" and "custCss" and i'm assining value in the declaration for only selectorText property and the custCss property is empty object as i'm assining but after the next line if i console log the value of the variable it shows the some css property inside the custCss property.

```js
let array = [{
  selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
  custCss: {
    'background-color': "yellow",
    color: "white"
  }
}, {
  selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
  custCss: {
    'background-color': "yellow"
  }
}, {
  selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
  custCss: {
    'background-color': "yellow"
  }
}];
let arr = array.map(function(val, idx) {
  let styleObject = {
    selectorText: val.selectorText,
    custCss: {}
  };
  if (idx === array.length - 1) {
    styleObject.custCss = val.custCss;
    return styleObject;
  }
  for (let index = idx + 1; index < array.length; index++) {
    (function(indx) {
      for (var prop in val.custCss) {
        if (array[indx].custCss.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
          styleObject.custCss[prop] = val.custCss[prop];
        }
      }
    })(index);
  }
  // console.log(newObj)
  return styleObject;
});

console.log(arr)
```

what this function does is map over the arr of object with the structure like this

```
 [{selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",custCss: {background-color: "yello",color: "white"}},{selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",custCss: {background-color: "yello"}},{selectorText: "a.classname , textfield",custCss: {background-color: "yello"}}]
```

#### step 1 = this map function loops over this array

#### inside this map function a simple for loop which loops from the next index not the current index

#### inside the for loop their is for in loop which loop over all the css property in the custCss property of the current element in map function and check if the property is available in the next css proerty present in the array

```
if the background-color present custCss object in the index 0  and also it is present in index 1 or 2 or later then we are  not setting this property to the styleObject custCss property. If a css property like color which is only presnet in the first index and not in the later index then we append this into the styleObject;
```

This code is basically to remove duplicates field from the custCss and only keeping the latest css property and also keeping the original structure of the array ---

### expected result

```
[{
      selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
      custCss: {
        color: "white"
      }
    }, {
      selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
      custCss: {
      }
    }, {
      selectorText: "a.classname , #textfield",
      custCss: {
        'background-color': "yellow"
      }
    }];
```

Comment: post the desired output too

Comment: desired out put is it should remove the custCss property if it is already present in the last or later index css and return the arr ;

Comment: let arr = [{selectorText: "some class name",custCss: {border: "none"}},{selectorText: "some class name",custCss: {border: "1px "}}];
out expected is arr = [{selectorText: "some Class name",custCss: {}},{selectorText: "some class name",custCss: {border: "1px"}}]

Comment: You don't have any element in array which has `border : 1px` value, and in your desired output you have `custCss : { border : "1px" }`, how ?

Comment: run the snippet it's already giving the desired result

Comment: But in the actual place where it run styleObject declaration custCss property is already set but i haven't set it

Answer (score 0):

Shorter code -

Create the `keys` array. Iterate over the array elements, get the keys of `custCss`, check if it is already present in the `keys` array, if yes delete the property.

```js
let arr = [{
  selectorText: "some Class name",
  custCss: {}
}, {
  selectorText: "some class name",
  custCss: {
    border: "1px"
  }
}];

const keys = [];

arr.reverse().forEach(({custCss}) => {
  const objKeys = Object.keys(custCss);
  objKeys.forEach((key) => {
    if (keys.includes(key)) {
      delete custCss[key];
    }
  });
  keys.push(...objKeys);
});

console.log(arr.reverse());
```